# r shinyapps deployment error when doing it manually

Tags: r, shinyapps

I have a shinnyapp on https://www.shinyapps.io/ that I can normally deploy the app using the "publish" button.

However I want to use instead the `deployApp` function as in the code bellow:

```
rsconnect::deployApp("~/Documents/R/shinny",appName="myapp", account="myaccount")
```

But  when using the `deployApp` function it gets an error on the web browser:

```
An error has occurred

The application failed to start: exited unexpectedly with code 1

Attaching package: ‘dplyr’

The following objects are masked from ‘package:plyr’:

    arrange, count, desc, failwith, id, mutate, rename, summarise,
    summarize

The following objects are masked from ‘package:stats’:

    filter, lag

The following objects are masked from ‘package:base’:

    intersect, setdiff, setequal, union

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : could not find function "dashboardPage"
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

So If push the button, no problem but if I use the function it goes wrong.

My Rscript structure is bellow ( there are more code inside the functions but I keep it simple to exemplify)

```
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
library(lubridate)
library(zoo)
library(reshape2)
library(scales)
library(ggrepel)
library(stringr)
load("sales.RData")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
                              
                            )
)

body <- dashboardBody(
)

ui <- fluidPage(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  sidebar,
  body
)
)


server <- function(input, output) {
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

rsconnect::deployApp('C:\\Users\\Repro\\Documents\\R\\SHINY', 
                     appFiles = c('app.R','sales.RData','www/custom.css'), 
                     account = 'myaccount', server = 'shinyapps.io')
```

What could be the problem ?

Thanks

Comment: Is `library(shiny)` or rather `library(shinydashboard)` at the head of your script ?

Comment: Hello. Both are included.

Comment: Is your app build in a Rproject with all scripts inside it? (maybe an hypothesis, cause we don't have your scripts so it's no easy).

Comment: Hello. I have updated the question with my app structure. Hope it can clarify.

Comment: Hello. When I deployApp, I don't put path in parameters, I build my application as an Rproject with RStudio and then just run `rsconnect::deployApp()` directly without any parameters. Can you try this?

Comment: Hi. I discovered my error. Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After trial and error I solved the problem.

My mistake was trying to execute the app.R script including the deploy script altogether.

When I run the deploy script separately as bellow, it works:

```
    rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='myaccount',
                          token='xxxxxxxxx',
                          secret='yyyyyyyy')

rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = 'C:\\Users\\Documents\\R\\SHINY',appFiles=c('app.R','sales.RData','www/custom.css'),
account = 'myaccount', server = 'shinyapps.io')
```